# Google sheet- How to auto fill a cell on selection of dropdown value?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

How to auto fill a cell on selection of dropdown value in google sheet?
Let say I have a table with two columns

```
| Text | Value |
```

i have used Text column to populate dropdown. And on selection of dropdown Text, we need a cell to be auto populated with it's corresponding Value.
Please suggest the approach?

Comment: Use `VLOOKUP` [function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318) for that.

Answer (score 3):

First you have to create “Text” and “Value” columns with their respective values (you can hide those rows later if you want). Then, you can proceed creating the dropdown list.

Try the following, I tested this and worked:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(B8:B),"",(VLOOKUP(B8:B,B2:C4,2,FALSE))))
```

[image]